# multiple find in a text file line and find the line number

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a text file that each line of it has 4 values. like this:

aaa:1000_bbbb:231_cccc:30002_ddd:323

i have a listbox that has values with this format

1222 111  23432 322  (4 subitems)

i want  for each listbox listitem i want to loop through text file lines and find weather there is similar values that matches my list items or not.

```
For i = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
if 'values are similar
msgbox "there is similarities" * "in line # of textbox

next
```

how should i do that?

Comment: which version of vb are you using? vb6 or vb.net? you tagged both..

Comment: are you using a listbox control or a listview control?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

which part do you have problems with?

some possible steps are as follows :

- you read in the text file completely
- or you read in the text file line by line
- you loop through all lines
- you split each line into 4 items
- you loop through all 4 items if needed
- you loop through all items in the listbox of listview
- if a similarity is found, you step out of the loop(s)